# Creating Magento Extension - Where to start?

Tags: magento

I want to make an extension that injects videos on product pages.

I already read a lot of documentation in Magento website but, sincerely, I have no clue where to start. What's the difference between Magento Extensions and Widgets? Can I develop my extension using only JavaScript? Do I really need to use PHP to develop one?

So many questions, can't find a focus. Can you please share a simple follow trough for me to read on? Thanks.

Comment: You could do that in simple way, like adding attribute(text) for link of product video and then simply can fetch it on product view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits : Marius

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/how-to-write-a-custom-extension/8345#8345

Here is what I usually do:

1. **Always develop with `error_reporting` on.**
2. **Always develop with `isDeveloperMode` set to `true`. Just add `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1` to your `httpd.conf` file (or corresponding file for nginx or something else)**
3. If the extension is linked to a core functionality add the
   dependency in the declaration file `<depends><Mage_Catalog /></depend>`
4. If the module is for community use, use `community` as codepool to
   give the developers the chance to override some classes without
   modifying the code directly
5. Put your frontend design files in `app/design/frontend/base/default`
   to make them available for all themes.
6. Put your admin design files in
   `app/design/adminhtml/default/default` and do not change the admin
   theme. I may want to change it in one of my modules.
7. Prefix your layout file names and template folder name with the
   company name to make it easier to isolate them.
   `easylife_articles.xml` and `app/design/.../easylife_articles`
8. Put your static resources (js, css, images) in a similar folder as
   the template files `easylife_articles/images/doh.png`
9. Attach a simple text file with how to uninstall the extension: What
   files need to be removed, what tables need to be dropped, what
   config settings need to be removed from `core_config_data` table.
10. Do not write queries directly in models, blocks or helpers, use a
     resource model for that.
11. Do not write queries using the table names directly `Select * from
     sales_flat_order where ...`. Use a `Zend_Select` and transform the
     table names using `->getTable('sales/order')`.
12. Use the base url to include `js` files in template. **Wrong**
     `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/some.js"></script>`.
     **Right** `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'some.js'?>"></script>`
13. Do not rewrite classes unless is necessary. Use observers and if
     it's not possible use helper methods that receive as parameter and
     instance of a class that you wanted to override. **Wrong**:
     Override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` to add the method
     `getProductArticles()`. **Right**. In your helper add
     `getProductArticles(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)`
14. If you override classes put a list of them in a `readme.txt` file
15. Use the default admin path for the admin section of your module.
     **Wrong admin url** `articles/adminhtml_articles/index`. **Right admin url** `admin/articles/index`
16. Add ACL for your admin sections. I may want to restrict access to
     some of the admins.
17. Do not add an other js framework (jquery, mootools, ...) if it's not
     necessary. Write you code in prototype.
18. Make you template html W3C valid (this is for OCD developers like myself).
19. Do not put images in the `media` folder. Use `skin`. The `media`
     folder usually is not versioned and this makes it harder to move the
     website on different environments.
20. Test you extension with flat catalog on and off. In order not to double the development time use [Chaos Monkey](http://alanstorm.com/magento_flat_collection_chaos)
21. Test your extension with cache `on` and cache `off`.
22. Avoid using uppercase letter in the module and class names. If not
     properly tested this may cause issues on different OS. This is more a recommendation, not a 'must'.
23. Dispatch events in your code to make it easier for developers to
     alter the functionality.
24. Follow the same coding standards that Magento uses and comment your code.
25. *[Edited]* Do not use php short tags (`<? $this->doSomething() ?>`). Use full tags (`<?php $this->doSomething()?>`). Also don't use short echo tags, yet. (`<?="D'oh";?>`). Use (`<?php echo "D'oh";?>`)
26. Translate your texts using `$this->__` and add the locale translation file with your texts (`app/local/en_US/Easylife_Articles.csv`) at least for `en_US` language. Not all
     websites are build in English and the identification of texts to
     translate is time consuming.
27. If you sell an extension offer at least basic support. Or at least
     answer the support e-mails you receive.
28. **Do not make constant calls to your servers through your extension for licence validation. Once, at installation is more than enough (I don't like this approach either, but it's better than to make calls all the time).
     (Inspired by [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8460/146))**
29. Develop with the log activated and from time to time take a look at
     the `var/log/system.log` file. The errors listed here are not shown
     even with developer mode on. If there is at least one error you end
     up with a large log file after a few months of running the extension.
30. If your extension affects the checkout process or the orders in
     some way, make sure it works with multi-shipping, or if it
     shouldn't work with multi-shipping, make sure it doesn't affect it.
31. **Do not replace the default Admin Notification bar (or feed URL). If
     I'm interested on what you have to offer I will subscribe to your
     newsletter. Let me see what Magento has to say. It's more important
     to me.**
32. **If you encrypt your code files with Ioncube (or something
     else)...well...I just hate you and I hope your business goes bankrupt**

That's what  have so far. I will add more as soon as I think of something else.

Comment: Some good points, though wishing that a fellow developer's business fails is vindictive, mean and nasty. Question: If someone has setup a plugin business and it is going to be their only revenue stream, and they have to be profitable quickly as they have commitments (family, mortgage, other employees), what works best in your experience to protect the revenue stream from losses due to people sharing the code or buying a license for one domain and using it on 10, giving it to their buddies etc? Maybe selling support licenses could work, but most don't like to pay for support.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need XML and PHP, because this is mainly what Magento is built on.

Additionally to the official documents, there are a lot of helpful and very diverse tutorials out there that explain the mechanics of Magento. A web search helps, and I can recommend everything by Alan Storm, for example this litte module: http://alanstorm.com/magento_list_module

As soon as creating an extension works for you, you will also find a lot of tutorials on how to alter the product-view, or you can then post a more specific question here or on [magento.stackexchange.com](http://magento.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks @simonthesorcerer, I will read the Alan Storm materials.